# Bidemensional array to bidemensional array using foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Hi I have the following array

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_acreditado"]=>
    string(3) "174"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(7) "4008.00"
    ["acreditado"]=>
    string(27) "Olga Olivia Lucio Hernandez"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_acreditado"]=>
    string(3) "175"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(7) "4008.00"
    ["acreditado"]=>
    string(23) "Enrique Carranco Vences"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_acreditado"]=>
    string(3) "176"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(7) "4008.00"
    ["acreditado"]=>
    string(32) "Juana Patricia Contreras Paredes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id_acreditado"]=>
    string(3) "177"
    ["cantidad"]=>
    string(7) "4008.00"
    ["acreditado"]=>
    string(17) "Noemi Cruz Campos"
  }
}
```

And I want to create a bidimensional array with some values of the above array and different indices. I'm using a foreach loop to achive that.

```
$j=1;
foreach($acreditados as $acreditado){
    $tmp['oneCol'] = $j;
    $tmp['twoCol'] = $acreditado['acreditado'];
    $tmp['threeCol'] = $acreditado['cantidad'];
    $info['fourCol'] =$acreditado['id_acreditado'];
    $info[]=$tmp;
    $j++;
}
```

$tmp is an auxiliar one dimension array that lately is added as a row for bidemensional $info array, however I'm not getting the output expected. I want something like the following as output:

```
array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["oneCol"]=>
        int(1)
["twoCol"]=>
        string(27) "Olga Olivia Lucio Hernandez"
        ["threeCol"]=>
        string(7) "4008.00"
["fourCol"]=>
        string(3) "174" 
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
 ["oneCol"]=>
        int(2)
["twoCol"]=>
        string(23) "Enrique Carranco Vences"
        ["threeCol"]=>
        string(7) "4008.00"
["fourCol"]=>
        string(3) "175"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
 ["oneCol"]=>
        int(3)
       ["twoCol"]=>
        string(32) "Juana Patricia Contreras Paredes"
        ["threeCol"]=>
        string(7) "4008.00"   
 ["fourCol"]=>
        string(3) "176"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(3) {
 ["oneCol"]=>
        int(4)
       ["twoCol"]=>
        string(17) "Noemi Cruz Campos"
        ["threeCol"]=>
        string(7) "4008.00"
 ["fourcol"]=>
        string(3) "177"
      }
    }
```

Comment: $tmp = array(); inside the forloop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a code error

The line

```
$info['fourCol'] =$acreditado['id_acreditado'];
```

Should be

```
$tmp['fourCol'] =$acreditado['id_acreditado'];
```

So the code show be: (With the added $tmp array reset)

```
$j=1;
foreach($acreditados as $acreditado){
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['oneCol'] = $j;
    $tmp['twoCol'] = $acreditado['acreditado'];
    $tmp['threeCol'] = $acreditado['cantidad'];
    $tmp['fourCol'] =$acreditado['id_acreditado'];
    $info[] = $tmp;
    $j++;
}
```